# Variances of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

So my girlfriend posed me this question, from an exam that she had to take:

Assume that the length of adult men and women is normally distributed with means of 182 cm and 168 cm respectively. Furthermore it is given that there is an equal proportion (50%) of men and women in the population, and that the standard deviation of length is the same for both groups. Somebody selects at random a person from the population and tells you the length of this person is 175 cm. If you want to minimize the probability of a wrong classification, you should predict (choose one of the options below):

(A) The person is male.

(B) The person is female.

(C) It doesn’t matter, the probabilities are equal.

(D) Not enough information was provided to decide on this matter.

The correct answer, according to the professor, was (D), as it is not given that variances are equal.

I thought that since the length of men and women are both normally distributed with the same standard deviation, their variances must also be equal. If this were real data, I might see some gaps, but since it's a theoretical exercise I don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: If standard deviations are the same for both groups (as it says in the question) then the variances are also the same for both groups. (What was this person a professor of?)

Comment: She studies data science. I'm an economist, so my first thought tends to be that the data scientist must be right.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer must be (C). Since the standard deviations are equal, so are the variances, as you say. And 175 is midway between the two means of 168 and 182, so the probabilities are equal.

You could calculate that formally using Bayes' theorem, but it is not necessary for answering the question.